# Orally designating a Shabas place without a landmark

Tags: maseches-eruvin, eruv-techumin

The *Mishna*, *Eruvin* 4:7, says that someone approaching his home before *Shabas* can designate a spot between his home and his current location as his *Shabas* location, and he gets a 2000-*ama* radius around that spot, so he can go home:

> One who was coming on the road and it was getting dark for him, and he recognized a tree or fence and said "My spending *Shabas* is under it" — he said nothing [because the area under the tree or fence is too large to be designated as a location for these purposes]. "My spending *Shabas* is at the base of [that tree]" — he [may] walk from the place his feet are in until its base, [up to] 2000 *amos*, and from its base until his home, [up to another] 2000 *amos*. It turns out he walks, after it gets dark, 4000 *amos*.

Then 4:8 continues:

> If he doesn't recognize [such a landmark], or is not an expert in *halacha* [to know that he can use the above rule], and he said [instead] "My spending *Shabas* is in my location", he has acquired his location for himself, 2000 *amos* in every direction.

Seemingly, then, this designation from afar must be at a tree or other landmark. "If he doesn't recognize" one, he can't do it. Why is that? Why can't he say "My spending *Shabas* is at the point 2000 *amos* in that direction" (pointing, or saying "east")? Why isn't that a good enough designation?

Comment: Maybe because an Eruv is an extreme leniency in Hilchos Shabbos, and so in order to avoid problems with walking out of the techum - an issur d'oraisa - Chazal wanted to make sure he knows exactly where his techum begins and ends? Not everyone had Rabbah Gamliel's telescope to measure 2000 amos (Eiruvin 43b), nor the ability to focus on exactly how many steps they've taken to measure when they reached 2000 amos from the techum (Yerushalmi Chagigah story about Acher).

Comment: @DonielF isn't the deoraisa 12000 amos?  (Or something like that)

Comment: @Heshy Take another look at Shemos 16, when they venture too far out on Shabbos to collect the man that wasn't there.

Comment: @DonielF what does that have to do with the shiur?

Comment: @Heshy Thats where the issur is brought down - that's where you should look for what the Shiur is, if not in the pesukim then in the Gemaras on those pesukim.

Comment: @DonielF Rambam Shabbos 27:1. Deoraisa it's 12 mil which is 24000 amos. 2000 is miderabanan

Comment: @DonielF its a Machlokes Tanaim. We Paskin that 2000 Amman limit is Derabanan.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara ([Eruvin 50b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01323.html#HtmpReportNum0097_L2)) seems to relate to your question and based on Rashi's explanation you have to designate an identifiable spot.

Even saying "*around that stone*" is sufficient.

However, just saying "*at the 2,000 Ama spot on the horizon*" is not considered a designation, since you cannot identify it, so you cannot designate it.

> **בד''א**. דבמקום שאינו מסויים קני ליה מיהא ד''א לשביתה ואלפים מהן לכל רוח: **במסיים ד''א**. שקבע בד' בהן שהיה לו בהן סימן אילן או אבן ואמר באותן ד' תהא שביתתי:‏

Comment: Yes, but… _why?_

Comment: "since you cannot identify it" - since he's essentially "moving homes" for Shabbat to a new location. You can't relocate to "somewhere"; you have to have an exact address.

Comment: Isn't "2000 ammot in *that* direction" a precise address?